# Spring autowiring and dependency injection using Java configuration

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to play around with the example shown here:

http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/

In this example, one class has a Component annotation and a member variable with the Autowired annotation. The auto-wired member of the class has the same type as a Bean in a @Configuration class also supplied in this example.

This sample code does a getBean call on the Component class and makes the call. The auto-wiring works and runs. This leads me to believe that both classes are loaded as beans managed by the spring container even though one class is not marked as a bean.

However, when I tried a slightly more complex example using this same pattern I'm getting a spring exception:

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

It seems like a class has to be labeled as a bean to get managed by spring, but the supplied example seems indicate otherwise.

My code is listed here (names have been changed):

Config.java

```
package com.mydomain.config;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class Config {

    @Bean
    A getAClass()
    {
          return new AImpl();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
          ApplicationContext context = 
              new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);

          B b = context.getBean(B.class);
          B.process();
      }
}
```

B.java

```
package com.mydomain.component;

@Component
public class B{

@Autowired
private A a;

public void process()
{       
     return a.process();    
}
```

A.java

```
package com.mydomain.component;

public interface A {
    void process(); 
}
```

AImpl.java

```
package com.mydomain.component;

public class AImpl implements A {
    void process()
    {   }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you paste your code, and the full stack trace of the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not enough for it to be annotated with `@Component`. The annotated class must be in a package that is component scanned.

Notice how the `@Configuration` class in the example has

```
@ComponentScan
```

this will make it scan the package of the class it is annotating. You can provide an attribute to the annotation

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.you.some")
```

to have it scan for components in that (those) specified package(s).